# Como fazer preload de imagens grandes?

Tags: jquery

Tenho um background de 2mb para fazer preload e não sei como fazer... Já tentei o básico, por exemplo:

```
$ ("#image"). load (function () {
}
```

Comment: Você quer fazer o preload apenas da imagem ou quer fazer um preload para mostrar a página apenas quando essa imagem estiver pronta?

Comment: mostrar a página apenas quando a imagem estiver pronta/carregada...

Answer (score 0):

Entendo que voce esteja querendo mostrar o seu site somente quando todas as imagens estejam carregadas. Desta forma basta utilizar:

```
$(window).load(function() { $('.principal').show(); })
```

**Ou**

```
$('body').load(function() { $('.principal').show(); })
```

Se voce nao desejar que o seu site apareça até que esteja 100% carregado. vc pode deixar uma div de carregando e outra com todo o conteúdo do site dentro onde a do site começe escondida.

**CSS:**

```
.principal { display: none; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="carregando">Carregando...</div>
<div class="principal"></div>
```

Comment: mas a página abre e a imagem ainda não tá carregada...já tinha tentando isso...